# How do we get $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=0}(h_t)_{ij}=\langle\nabla_{e_i}X,e_j\rangle+\langle e_i,\nabla_{e_j}X\rangle$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

Sorry, I will have to begin my question by directly pasting a few snapshots. The following material comes from *Geometric Relativity* by Dan A. Lee.

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

I'd like to derive equation (2.4). What I have tried so far is that if $h_t=\Phi_t^*h$, we would obtain $h_t=\Phi_t^*g$. Since $d\Phi_t$ is an isomorphism, we should agree that $(e_i(t))$ is a local frame on $\Sigma_t$. It follows that
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(h_t)_{ij}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\langle e_i(t),e_j(t)\rangle_{h_t}\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\Phi_t^*g)(e_i,e_j)\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g_{\Phi_t}(e_i(t),e_j(t)).
\end{align}$$
Now I wonder why equation (C) is possible. Are there any tricks? Thank you.

**Edit.** I got some ideas though still lost in equation (C). To arrive at equation (2.4), you can substitute $t=0$ into equation (E). To get (E), you can use equality of mixed partials to conclude the Lie bracket of $X_t$ and $e_i(t)$ is the zero vector field. Finally, equation (D) can be derived using the fact that Levi-Civita connections are metric connections.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I disagree with your first line $(h_t)_{i,j} = \left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_{h_t}$ which should be $\left<e_i,e_j\right>_{h_t}$, which is what Lee wrote at equation $(A)$. Indeed, $h_t$ is a metric on $\Sigma$ and not on $\Sigma_t$. If $\iota_t : \Sigma_t \hookrightarrow M$ is your inclusion, $\iota_t^*g$ is the metric on $\Sigma_t$ induced by $g$ and $h_t = \Phi_t^*\iota_t^*g$ is a metric on $\Sigma$ (it is the defintion of $h_t$). Remember that each $(h_t)_{i,j}$ is a smooth function from an open subset of $\Sigma$ (and not $\Sigma_t$ !) in $\mathbb{R}$.

You have in fact, for all $x \in \Sigma$ where the $(e_i)$ are defined,
\begin{align*}
(h_t)_{i,j}(x) & = \left<e_i(x),e_j(x)\right>_{h_t(x)}\\
& = \left<e_i(x),e_j(x)\right>_{\Phi_t^*g(x)} \textrm{ where I skipped the $\iota_t^*$ by abuse of notation.}\\
& = \left<d\Phi_t(x)e_i(x),d\Phi_t(x)e_j(x)\right>_{g(\Phi_t(x))}\\
& = \left<e_i(t)(\Phi_t(x)),e_j(t)(\Phi_t(x))\right>_{g(\Phi_t(x))}\\
& = \Phi_t^*(\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_{g})(x),\\
\end{align*}
which is equation $(B)$ without the $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ and evaluated at a point $x$.

Now, the trick is to notice that $e_i(t)$ can be extended to an open subset of $M$ and that it doesn't really depend on the time $t$ in the sense that $\frac{\partial e_i}{\partial t}(t) = 0$ when we are on $\Sigma_t$. Indeed, take one point $x_0 \in \Sigma$ and extend each $e_i$ in an open neighborhood of $x_0$ (it is always possible to do that) and let extend $e_i(t)$ with $e_i(t)(y) = d\Phi_t(\Phi_t^{-1}(y))e_i(\Phi_t^{-1}(y))$ which exists in a neighborhood of $\Phi_t(x_0) \in \Sigma_t$ and extends $e_i$.

Therefore, $t,y \mapsto e_i(t)(y)$ exists in an open subset of $]-\epsilon,\epsilon[ \times M$ so $\frac{\partial e_i}{\partial t}$ makes sens. Now, we have by definition that for $x$ close enough to $x_0$,
$$
e_i(t)(\Phi_t(x)) - d\Phi_t(x)e_i(x) = 0
$$
thus when we differentiate with respect to $t$,
\begin{align*}
0 & = \frac{\partial e_i}{\partial t}(t)(\Phi_t(x)) + de_i(t)(\Phi_t(x))\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi_t(x) - d\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi_t(x)e_i(x)\\
& = \frac{\partial e_i}{\partial t}(t)(\Phi_t(x)) + de_i(t)(\Phi_t(x))X_t(\Phi_t(x)) -d(X_t \circ \Phi_t)(x)e_i(x)\\
& = \frac{\partial e_i}{\partial t}(t)(\Phi_t(x)) + de_i(t)(\Phi_t(x))X_t(\Phi_t(x)) - dX_t(\Phi_t(x))d\Phi_t(x)e_i(x)\\
& = \frac{\partial e_i}{\partial t}(t)(\Phi_t(x)) + de_i(t)(\Phi_t(x))X_t(\Phi_t(x)) - dX_t(\Phi_t(x))e_i(t)(\Phi_t(x))\\
& = \left(\frac{\partial e_i}{\partial t}(t) - [X_t,e_i(t)]\right)(\Phi_t(x)).
\end{align*}
We deduce that $\frac{\partial e_i}{\partial t}(t) = [X_t,e_i(t)]$ when it is well defined. In particular, on $\Sigma_t$, $[X_t,e_i(t)] = 0$ (I didn't verify it but you said you proved it) so $\frac{\partial e_i}{\partial t} = 0$ (notice that we can't conclude that $e_i$ is locally constant with repect to time since it only works on $\Sigma_t$, not on the open set where the $e_i(t)$ have been continued).

Now, we have the tools to conclude. When we are close enough to $x_0$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi_t^*\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g & = \Phi_t^*\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g + \Phi_t^*(d\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi_t(x)\\
& = \Phi_t^*\left(\left<\frac{\partial e_i}{\partial t}(t),e_j(t)\right>_g + \left<e_i(t),\frac{\partial e_j}{\partial t}(t)\right>_g\right) + \Phi_t^*(d\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g)\Phi_t^*X_t\\
& = \Phi_t^*\left(\left<\frac{\partial e_i}{\partial t}(t),e_j(t)\right>_g + \left<e_i(t),\frac{\partial e_j}{\partial t}(t)\right>_g + d\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_gX_t\right)\\
& = \Phi_t^*\left(\left<\frac{\partial e_i}{\partial t}(t),e_j(t)\right>_g + \left<e_i(t),\frac{\partial e_j}{\partial t}(t)\right>_g + X_t\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g\right).
\end{align*}
And at a point $x \in \Sigma$, we have $\Phi_t(x) \in \Sigma_t$ so the $\frac{\partial e_i}{\partial t}$ vanish and,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(h_t)_{i,j} = \Phi_t^*(X_t\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g).
$$
It is equation $(C)$. I don't know however if it is the fastest method, maybe you can prove $(C)$ without extending the $e_i$ but you will struggle to compute the derivative with respect to time since the domain of definition of $e_i(t)$ changes when $t$ changes.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt assistance. I'm still working on it, but I think you deserve the bounty because of how you treated a complete stranger like me. Thanks again.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the partial derivative of $$\Phi_t^*\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g?$$ I don't know how to differentiate $$\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g\circ\Phi_t$$  with respect to $t$.

Comment: Write $f(t,y) = \left<e_i(t)(y),e_j(t)(y)\right>_{g(y)}$ and $g(t,x) = \Phi_t(x)$. Then $\Phi_t^*(\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g)(x) = f(t,g(t,x))$ by definition. And you have $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(f(t,g(t,x))) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,g(t,x))\frac{\partial t}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t,g(t,x))\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(t,x)$ by the chain rule.

Comment: And in this case, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,g(t,x)) = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g\right)(\Phi_t(x)) = \Phi_t^*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g\right)(x)$.

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t,g(t,x)) = (d\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g)(\Phi_t(x)) = \Phi_t^*(\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g)(x)$.

Finally, $\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(t,x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi_t(x)$. I hope it is more clear !

Comment: Thank you, but how would you explain the magic formula $$d\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_gX_t=X_t\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g?$$ Following your steps, I think the operator $d$ is $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$. Now, what does $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ really mean? What is its action on the inner product? Thank you.

Comment: Here, $y$ is a point of $M$ so differentiating with respect to $y$ means taking the exterior derivative $d$ on $M$. We want to compute $d\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_gX_t$ ($t$ is fixed) but this is by definition $X_t\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g$ (it works the same with any smooth function instead of $\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g$). In general, $df(x)$ is a linear form $T_xM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $df(x)(X(x)) = (Xf)(x)$. This directly comes from the bijection between tangent space and space of derivations.

Comment: Despite my gratitude towards your kindly help, I claim that there is a multiplication sign between $d\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g$ and $X_t$, which makes us unable to consider $d\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_gX_t$ to be the value of $1$-form $d\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>_g$ at $X_t$.

Comment: I'm sorry if my notations are unclear but it is not a multicplication, it is the evaluation of a $1$-form. Indeed, for $t$ fixed, $\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>$ is a smooth function $M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Thus, $d\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>$ is a $1$-form $TM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $d\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>X_t$ is the evaluation of this $1$-form defined by $(d\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>X_t)(y) = d\left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>(y)(X_t(y)) \in \mathbb{R}$. And this is precisely $X_t \cdot \left<e_i(t),e_j(t)\right>$ where $\cdot$ means the derivation with respect to the vector field $X_t$.

Comment: I'm still confused. After doing the chain rule $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(f(t,g(t,x))) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,g(t,x))\frac{\partial t}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t,g(t,x))\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(t,x),$$ you did really get a multiplication sign between $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t,g(t,x))$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(t,x)$, right?

Comment: No, it is actually the evaluation of the differential $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. What confused you is probably the notation $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ which denotes the $n$-variables differentation on $M$ ($y \in M$) I should have written $d$ instead maybe, but I wanted to make clear that the time $t$ is fixed. When $f : M \times N \rightarrow P$ is smooth with $M,N,P$ smooth manifolds, you can consider for each point $(x,y) \in M \times N$ three different differentials for $f$,

$d_{M \times N}f(x,y) : T_xM \times T_yN \rightarrow T_{f(x,y)}P$,...

Comment: ...$d_Mf(x,y) : T_xM \rightarrow T_{f(x,y)P}$ where $y$ is fixed and we only differentiate with repsect to $x$ and $d_Nf(x,y) : T_yN \rightarrow T_{f(x,y)}P$ where it is the opposite.

They are related by $d_{M \times N}f(x,y)(v,w) = d_Mf(x,y)v + d_Nf(x,y)w$ which is the chain rule (you exaclty obtain the classical chain rule on $\mathbb{R}^2$ when $M = N = P = \mathbb{R}$).

I use this with $M \leftarrow \mathbb{R}$ (the time $t$), $N \leftarrow M$ (the variable $y$) and $P \leftarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I wish I could understand what you are talking about. This is really far beyond my knowledge. Where did you learn it? Any books recommended? Thank you.

Comment: It's actually not hard to understand. Differentiation is a local operation so we may assume $M = \mathbb{R}^m$, $N = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $P = \mathbb{R}^p$. Then, $f : (x_1,\ldots,x_m,y_1,\ldots,y_n) \mapsto (f_1(x,y),\ldots,f_p(x,y))$ is simply $p$ smooth functions of $m + n$ variables. Then, $d_{M \times N}f(x,y)(v,w) = \sum_{i = 1}^m \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x,y)v_i + \sum_{j = 1}^m \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_j}(x,y)w_j$. You get $d_Mf$ by fixing $y$ and differentiating with respect to $x$, $d_Mf(x,y)v = \sum_{i = 1}^m \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x,y)v_i$. Same thing for $y$.